# Easy way to turn plain text into .bat file

Tags: excel, performance, batch-file

I need to write lots of .bat files to do this routine:

Open a blank excel sheet.
Sendkeys to the sheet to write a list of "labes" and a lot of calculation functions
Run a macro to protect the sended data labels and the functions,
Wait for the user to imput all the requested data (nexto the labels)
Check that all the fields are true data ( check against upper and lower limit)
Print out a report to a pdf file or paper
Compile a log with the report content 
And finally, erase and close the excel file.

Since the labels and the functions contains lots of special characters used in the sendkeys code, I need to know how to simply write it as plain text and THEN "auto turn" all the % sign and all the other special keys functions, in {%} when needed but not always... e.g

the batch lines sounds like this:

```
rem power 01 50% label
%SendKeys% "power up to 50{%} in {tab}seconds{return}"
rem power 01 latency
%SendKeys% "=c55/0,981*c72*(c73-(c73/100)){return}"
rem power 01 60% label
%SendKeys% "po
```

thanks for all!

Comment: to use `sendkeys` you need vbscript/jscript or powershell.But they already has activex object to deal with excel.Why sendkeys?

Comment: Hi, this will be part of a crf21 part 11 software. I need a quick way to create the code. At the moment I use sendkeys via .bat file to collect and output this data and to create the "an unformatted form"... I don't know how to explain it in other words.
Actually there is no reason to use one or another... %SendKeys% is the simplest I found to do that boring job...

Comment: To give more information, I can tell you that I have a list of products ( about 50000 items) everyone of this have to be chemically, phisically and biologically analyzed in different way with different tecniques that give different results data type. And also every product code has hundreds of batch of different size to be analyzed.

Comment: Instead of describe your "method" (excel, sendkeys, etc.), could you post an example of the input data, describe the process to be applied on it, and describe the desired output? I don't understand the role that Excel plays here (there are multiple ways to evaluate calculations). Perhaps this way we may help you...

Comment: If you are using Excel, then you should investigate Visual Basic for Applications (VBA). Batch files are not a good choice to interact with Excel.